A cocyclic module which is cyclic is simple
This question comes from a proof about proving a module is simple.
Let $A$ be a ring with an identity and $M$be a $A$-module. $M$ be a cocyclic $A$-module with a nonzero vector $m$,
i.e. every nontrivial submodule $U\subset M$  contains $m$.
To prove $M$ is simple.
Firstly, the author  proves $M$ is  a cocyclic $A$-module, i.e. there exists a nonzero vector $m$ such that every nontrivial submodule $U\subset M$  contains $m$.
Then the author proves $M$ is also a cyclic $A$-module.
Finally, the author says a cocyclic module which is cyclic is simple
My question is that  how to prove this.
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

This is false. Take $A=M=k[x]/(x^2)$. Then $M$ is cyclic and cocylic (take $m=x$) but is not simple.

@AndrewHubery Thanks you. Maybe I know what the problem is.
